# Using char arrays to add together large numbers

Tags: c++

I have an assignment in which I am supposed to
1.) Read in 2 char arrays of numbers
2.) add together the arrays, performing carry addition, carrying the tens place
3.) print out the newly added array.

I am also supposed to print an error if I need to carry on the last digit of the array (overflow)
so something like 99999999999999999999  +
                                     1  =
                  ________________________
                         ERROR

That's the part I'm having trouble with. 
The above outputs something like "99999999999999999:0" so I have no idea what's going wrong.

I'll post my code, but please be nice :( I know it certainly isn't the most efficient, but I'm just trying to lay things out in a way that is easy for my brain to understand right now.
And yes, I **HAVE** to use char arrays. I guess it's to help us understand the ascii table.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void InitNumber(char[]);
int AddArrays(char first[],  char second[], char combined[]);
void OutputNumber (char[]);

const int LENGTH = 20; // global variable

int main()
{

char set1[LENGTH];
char set2[LENGTH];
char sum[LENGTH];
InitNumber (set1);
InitNumber (set2);
if(AddArrays (set1, set2, sum)) {
    cout << "overflow!" << endl;

}

OutputNumber(sum);
}


void InitNumber (char list[])
{
int numberOfDigits;
cout << "Please enter the number of digits in the number: ";
cin >> numberOfDigits;
cout << "Please enter the digits in the number with the LEAST significant first: ";
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDigits; i++) {
    cin >> list [i]; 
}
for (int l=(numberOfDigits); l < LENGTH; l++) {
    list [l] = '0'; 
}
}
int AddArrays(char first[],  char second[], char combined[])
{
for (int h = 0; h < LENGTH; h++)
    combined[h]= '0';

int overflow = 0;


for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {

    int currentSum = (first[i]-'0' + second[i]-'0');
    cout << "currentSum = " << currentSum << endl;
    if(currentSum / 10 == 0 )
        combined[i] += currentSum;
    else if (currentSum/10 !=0) {
        if (i == LENGTH-1 && currentSum/10 !=0){
            overflow = 1;

        }
        else{
        combined [i]  += currentSum%10;
        cout << "current i: " << combined[i] << endl;

        combined [i+1] += currentSum/10;
        cout << "current i+1: " << combined[i+1] << endl;
        }
        }


    }

return overflow;
}



void OutputNumber(char arrayOut[])
{
for (int l=LENGTH - 1; l >= 0; l--)
        cout << arrayOut[l];
}
```

**working input**
**input**
6
1 2 3 4 5 6
7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7

**output**
00000000000008308642

Not-working output

**input**
20
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 
1
1

**output**
999999999999999999:0

Comment: Posting your code is a good first step to asking a good question. The second half is pointing out exactly what isn't working. Is your code segfaulting? Getting incorrect output? Hanging?

Comment: Ya you actually need to ask a question to get helpful answers.

Comment: The *character* `:` is what you get if you add 1 to the *character* `9` -- in ASCII. Presumably you need to check for this 'internal' overflow (where your problem statement only acknowledges it as a problem when the result does not fit anymore in the allocated space). What do you get for the simple test `9+1`?

Comment: The program prints 00000000000000000010 as it should. The issue is when the last digit needs to be carried, I'm just not sure why it's adding one to nine instead of checking to see if 10/10 = 1 first.

Comment: Please also post the sample input that is eliciting the naughty behavior from the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to reproduce small parts of your inner loop where you are carrying out the addition, in order to explain why your overflow detection is broken.

```
for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
    int currentSum = (first[i]-'0' + second[i]-'0');
    if(currentSum / 10 == 0 )
        combined[i] += currentSum;
```

Here you're adding the corresponding pair of digits from the two numbers you're adding, and checking (in your particular style) if they overflowed. Try to remember this part, it's important. In order to check for overflow, you're only checking the result of adding the pair of digits from the two large numbers you're adding.

```
    else if (currentSum/10 !=0) {
```

This is a completely useless check. You can only get here if the division is known to produce a non-zero result. This if() can be removed completely. Now, the relevant part of your code is

```
    combined [i]  += currentSum%10;
    combined [i+1] += currentSum/10;
```

Do you see the problem yet?

Your approach is, once overflow is detected, is to increment the next higher order digit in the result.

Unfortunately, on the next loop iteration, in order to check for carry over, you're just checking the sum of the next corresponding digit pair, from the two large numbers you're adding. The carry-over you're saving here is going to get completely ignored.

Say your numbers are two digits long max, rather than 20, and you entered the numbers 99 and 1.

- On the first iteration, you'll add 9 and 1, save 0 as the first digit, and add 1 to the second digit in the sum.
- On the second iteration, you'll add 9 and 0, and, given your logic above, conclude that nothing overflowed.

Comment: You're completely right, I changed it so that it tests (currentSum + combined[i])  against the division and mod by 10. Thanks!

Comment: You've only asked what was wrong with your overflow detection, so I limited my answer accordingly; but your overall approach is too complicated. It's been my experience that over-complicated logic is a frequent source of bugs. You should've also asked how to simplify this. This entire long addition can be reduced to only a few lines of code, without any if() statements inside the loop at all. In pseudocode: carry=0; for (i=iterate over the digits) { sum=carry+a[i]+b[i]; result[i]=sum % 10; carry=sum/10; } if (carry) { // You overflowed }